# EXECUTE AS LOGIN failed with local windows group login

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm troubleshooting a permission issue that I tried to perform the query below

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'ComputerName\Windows Group Name';

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');  

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE'); 

SELECT *
FROM sys.login_token
WHERE principal_id > 0;

revert;
```

It throws error at the first line with the message below

> Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal
> "ComputerName\Windows Group Name" does not exist, this type of
> principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

I confirmed the windows group and the login exists.
I search the error message and it seems people who faced the same error are not run into this while using windows group login.

Is it some native limitation or there is something I missed?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `name must be a singleton account, and cannot be a group, role, certificate, key, or built-in account, such as NT AUTHORITY\LocalService, NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService, or NT AUTHORITY\LocalSystem.`

Comment: You are right. So in my use case it should be `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'ComputerName\UserName'` that user is in `'ComputerName\Windows Group Name'` group. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can only impersonate login that appears in `sys.server_principals`

here an example from microsoft doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#_user